# Pass Uploaded File path To File.read(path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEXcl.png)

As you can see from the picture, i have a button to upload a csv file.
How can i get the uploaded file to file.read(PATH) so the script takes the file in.

My Controller (calls_controller.rb)

```
  def index

    csv_text = File.read(UPLOADED FILE PATH)
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1', :col_sep => ',')
  ...
  ..
  end
```

I tried to give my index method an argument

```
  def index(file)
```

but that did not work for me.

This is my view (index.html.erb).
I call out the method in the submit_tag, but can i somehow pass an argument or ?.

```
<div>
  <h4>Import data!</h4>
  <%= form_tag import_calls_path, multipart: true do  %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file, required: true %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV", method: :index%>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the file stored ? You would need to download the file to some path and then provide the path to the file to `File.read`

Comment: I actually have no idea, i have not changed it anywhere, but if thats the case then il try to find it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you upload a file with a form like the one in your question then the following should work:

```
File.read(params[:file].tempfile.path)
```

Or even simpler:

```
params[:file].read
```

Comment: `csv_text = File.read(params[:file])` 
Gives me an error "no implicit conversion of nil into String"
tried diffrent ways, but non worked.
With .read at the end too. Same error

Comment: How do the request and the params look like in the log file when sending the form?